# Could you help me to find a mistake in a Loop (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, loops

This code doesn't work, I tried to made a loop.

IF it possible to made return without creating new array and counter, that would be great! I the "basic" lang there were a function goto, that just return to needed line. Maybe something like this in JS?

**Here the code**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userAge = new Array ();
var loopCounter;
for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter > 1; loopCounter++) {
  var userAge[loopCounter] = prompt ("Enter your age please!");
  if (isNaN(userAge[loopCounter])) { 
   alert ("Enter Number value please! "); 
  } else {   
     if (userAge[loopCounter] == 0) {
       alert ("You are a baby");
     } else if ((userAge[loopCounter] <0) || (userAge[loopCounter] >=200)) {
       alert ("I think you are lying about your age!");
     } else {
       alert ("That\'s a good age!");
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is wrong.

`loopCounter`  initialized to `0` and checking it against `> 1` which will always be false. Hence, the loop never runs

```
for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter > 1; loopCounter++)
```